# Receiving Data from Web iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

It's the first time I have done anything like this but wondered what the best way to approach this would be.

I need a web interface which I could enter text, photos and videos, once submitted this can then be seen by users using the app through different feeds and things.

I know its a common thing but what techniques and things should I be learning? I'm not sure where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated as any information would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some links on documentation:

> 1. [URL Loading system programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)
> 2. [UIWebView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
> 3. [NSURLConnectionDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

There is also `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`
I would also recommend you [great book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021728.do) by Vandad Nahavandipoor.
The book [iOS 5 Programming Pushing the Limits](http://iosptl.com/) seems great to me.
Good luck.